# Finding high-resolution land cover data for Taiwan?

Tags: data, land-cover, land-classification, land-use, taiwan

So far, the best data I've found is from Globeland 30 (30 m), but the data for Taiwan is not very discriminant in partitioning the landscape.

Does anyone know of better resolution data?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check out the [USGS Land Cover Institute](http://landcover.usgs.gov/globallandcover.php).  Multiple land cover datasets and projects are referenced in the link.